# Two virtually identical pieces of jquery code working differently

Tags: jquery, html

In the example (see link) three of the four buttons open up a lightbox. The sequence is as follows:

1. User Clicks
2. Background fades to black
3. Lightbox Appears
4. Lightbox content fades in

This should happen every time the user clicks on the link, even if they have already opened that lightbox previously. For two of the links (top right and bottom left) it works just fine, but for the other one (top left) it works fine the first time the user clicks but after closing the lightbox and reopening, the content is already there and appears to 'fly in' from the right. The code for the lightboxes is identical, apart from ID tags.

Why is this happening?!!

The link to view is:

http://testing.xenongroupadmin.com/whatis/pfi/#

and the Jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a#show-whopanel").click(function(){
  $("#lightbox").fadeIn(300, function(){
   $("#who-panel").show(600, function(){
   $("#animation1").fadeIn(1000)
   });
  });
 });
 $("a#close-panel1").click(function(){
  $("#lightbox, #who-panel").fadeOut(300, function(){
   $("div#animation1").hide(300);
   }
  );
 });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a#show-whatpanel").click(function(){
  $("#lightbox").fadeIn(300, function(){
   $("#what-panel").show(600, function(){
   $("#animation2").fadeIn(1000)
   });
  });
 });
 $("a#close-pane2").click(function(){
  $("#lightbox, #what-panel").fadeOut(300, function(){
   $("div#animation2").hide(600);
   }
  );
 });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a#show-prosconspanel").click(function(){
  $("#lightbox").fadeIn(300, function(){
   $("#proscons-panel").show(600, function(){
   $("#animation3").fadeIn(1000)
   });
  });
 });
 $("a#close-panel3").click(function(){
  $("#lightbox, #proscons-panel").fadeOut(300, function(){
   $("div#animation3").hide(600);
   }
  );
 });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like it should cause that, but the hide time for the #animation1 is 300 where it's 600 for the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Turns out there was no problem with the JQuery code. Simply in the HTML Markup, the div element that was used to fade the screen to black was *below* the div for the first lightbox panel, but *above* the other two. I took it out and moved it to the top and Hey Presto! - it works!

Comment: I was wondering why the example page seemed to work perfectly well... that explains it.